# Secure way to run have sbt task launch subprocess with `sudo`

Tags: scala, scripting, sbt

I'm doing some DevOps scripting with SBT, and I need a Task to launch a subprocess via `sudo` where the user can securely type in their password through to the `sudo` prompt. Is there a way in sbt to allow a subprocess to temporarily yet fully capture the console's `stdin`, passing through the password keystrokes to `sudo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

You can use the following code in your `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`:

```
import sbt.Process

val sudo = taskKey[Unit]("Executes commands with sudo!")

sudo := {
  Process("sudo ls /", new File(".")).!<
}
```

You have to change `"sudo ls /"` with the actual command you want to run and `"."` with the directory you want to run that command in.

This is probably the safest option as you are connecting the standard input to the forked process but the downside is the current process will be blocked until the newly spawned process is terminated.

### How this works

[Sbt Process](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html) and [`ProcessBuilder`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.ProcessBuilder) have a lot of useful utilities for working with processes.

From Scaladocs of `!<` method:

> Starts the process represented by this builder, blocks until it exits, and returns the exit code.  Standard output and error are sent to the console.  The newly started process reads from standard input of the current process.

If you don't want to block the current process, then the task will be a bit more difficult. In that case you have to use a [`ProcessIO`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.ProcessIO) and provide inputs to its input stream, but then there is no secure way to get the password from standard input.

#### Alternative

Also note that `String`, `File`, and `URL` classes will be implicitly converted to a `ProcessBuilder` from which you can run a `Process`. So you can use the following code instead:

```
sudo := "sudo ls /".!<
```

In this case the current working directory of the running Java process will be used as the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this done in SBT, but I can recommend adding the user (or the user's group) and the command in the sudoers list so it doesn't prompt for a password.

I do exactly this with great success running some Docker tasks from SBT.

E.g. in `build.sbt`:

```
docker := {
  (test in Test).value
  (stage in Docker).value
  "./docker-stuff.sh" !
}
```

...and then `docker-stuff.sh` has the `sudo` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, in my use case, I can't force the user to make a system change like that.